# newbie at C++, confused with this result "no suitable constructor to convert from"const char [18] to "SimpleWordSearch"

Tags: c++

I've got this code, and I keep on getting this error, id tried to build constructors in the other classes that i thought could do this but it hasn't  worked

```
int main(int, char **) {

    ACW_Wrapper wrapper("log.txt");
    // Test simple algorithm
    {
        SimpleWordSearch ws = SimpleWordSearch();
        SimpleWordSearch ws = "output_simple.txt";

        Timer timer = Timer(); 

        wrapper.startTimer();
        ws.ReadSimplePuzzle();
        ws.ReadSimpleDictionary();
        const double LoadTime = wrapper.stopTimer();

        wrapper.startTimer();
        ws.SolveSimplePuzzle();
        const double SolveTime = wrapper.stopTimer();

        ws.WriteSimpleResults( LoadTime, SolveTime);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: With the give info, it's impossible to reproduce, provide a [mcve].

Comment: We don't know what `SimpleWordSearch` is, but those first two lines don't look right. Can you explain in more detail why you wrote them that way?

Comment: Why are you declaring `ws` twice?

Comment: simple wordsearch is the class that holds the logic for reading and solving a simple wordsearch.

Comment: but i declared ws twice as a mistake, i was trying to see if i could declare the simple wordsearch class first then getting it to work with "output etc.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `SimpleWordSearch` class looks like, but this I notice:

1. You're declaring a variable of type `SimpleWordSearch`
2. You're initializing it with a value of a `const char[]` (string) literal.
3. Your `SimpleWordSearch` variable cannot directly initialize with a `const char []` value as it does not have a constructor with a `const char []` argument

I believe you need either create a `SimpleWordSearch(const char [])` constructor or use (create?) whatever method or property a `SimpleWordSearch` class has to assign a value.

Comment: Well yes, `SimpleWordSearch ws = "output_simple.txt";` is declaration and assignment. 
I also just noticed it's declared twice. Not sure why the compiler is letting that go.

Comment: Yes I saw that I had accidentally used `char**` instead of `char*`. `const char[]` and `char*` are essentially equivalent types, are they not?

Comment: `=` is assignment, even if it's in the same statement as the declaration.

Comment: Well... my apologies on terminology. I've been in other languages land for a while. Thought I had this one.

Comment: @ayemossum Duplicate definition of two variables with the same name is allowed, although it should be never used. The second one masks the first one.

Comment: I don't think OP's question can be usefully answered in its current form, but your attempt looks OK to me (and it's no longer blatantly wrong).

Comment: @melpomeme, is there a way i could have asked it better, the issue for me is that i have the rest of the program working separate from this template, its that declaration i'm stuck on

Comment: @J.Dole Yes, see Ulrich Eckhardt's comment and read the linked explanation.